# Delphi, database for lan & web

Tags: delphi

I have a small database application in Delphi which for now works on a Lan.
I would like to make it also works through Web.
Which is the most appropriate approach?

I know that the most popular way is Php & Javascript but I don't have time to learn them.
So I prefer to stick with Delphi, or some 3rd party approach very close to Delphi programming.

I am using Datasnap C/S and MySQL.

PS I can see that IntraWeb is very close to VCL. Is it a wise solution?

Thanks in advance.

George, Greece.

Comment: Do you want to have a web application which will access your database over the Internet or you want your current desktop application to be able to connect you your database from the Internet?

Comment: I want the first one, second seems attractive but it's not my 1st priority.

Comment: If I were you I would try out various options. What works for one person may not work for you in your environment.

Comment: Which options you would try?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think that Delphi is not capable yet for Web-based database applications.
Finally, I may be try PHP.